# Проблема с вертикальной прокруткой страницы при использовании слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

Добрый день!
На сайте есть слайдер. Код взят с [OwlCarousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/).

Проблема в том, что на мобильной версии слайдер мешает прокрутке страницы. Слайдер принимает касание за перемещение слайдов. 
Отключение использования касания на мобильной версии не дает прокручивать страницу. Все равно приходится "тыкать" не на слайдер и только тогда сайт можно прокручивать.

Как можно это исправить? У меня даже нет идей для костылей

**UPD**
класс .owl-item имеет свойство user-select: none, которое никаким образом не отключается через стандартные настройки плагина. 
Имеет смысл его отключить, если Вы хотите нормальное прокручивание страницы с плагином. 
Вопрос исчерпан.

Comment: можно убрать касания и добавить вместо них кнопки с управлениями.

Comment: задать в опциях `touchDrag: false`

Comment: @Heidel Как я написал выше - ситуации не меняет. Касание блочится слайдером и поднять или опустить страницу нельзя

Comment: Ну, мне кажется это все-таки должно регулироваться в свойствах плагина, попробуйте другие свойства поменять. Как костыль - в мобильной версии натянуть поверх слайдера прозрачный див с абсолютным позиционированием и большим z-index.

Comment: @Heidel Нашел стиль user-select, которое стояло на всем плагине. Именно оно мешало скролить страницу на телефонах.

Comment: @NickCoolberg о как интересно))